# pyspark — best way to sum values in column of type Array(StringType()) after splitting

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this,

```
name | scores
Dan  |  [1_10, 2_5, 3_2, 4_12.5]
Ann  |  [2_12.4, 3_4.5, 5_9.3]
Jon  |  [2_1.7]
```

For each row, I want to extract the number value (split item on underscored and take the index 1) from the items in the scores column which is a string and sum up the column.

My expected answer will look like this,

```
name | Total
Dan  |  29.5
Ann  |  26.2
Jon  |  1.7
```

My data frame is very huge, the array column can contain millions of items in the worst case. Explode based on solution is not working out for me due to huge size of dataframe after explode.

My driver is small and I can't afford to run a UDF to solve this.

Can RDD or map can help here? If so how to use it efficiently? I'm running pyspark 2.3 btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` and `transform` higher order functions:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr('name', """
    aggregate(
        transform(scores, x -> split(x, '_')[1]),
        double(0),
        (acc, x) -> acc + x
    ) as Total
""")
```

For older spark versions, try explode and group by:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'scores', F.explode('scores').alias('scores')
).withColumn(
    'scores', F.split('scores', '_')[1]
).groupBy('name').agg(F.sum('scores').alias('Total'))
```

An RDD solution:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

df2 = df.rdd.map(lambda r: Row(name=r.name, Total=sum([float(i.split('_')[1]) for i in r.scores]))).toDF()

df2.show()
+----+-----+
|name|Total|
+----+-----+
| Dan| 29.5|
| Ann| 26.2|
| Jon|  1.7|
+----+-----+
```

Comment: Ah, probably won't. They were introduced in Spark 2.4.

Comment: yep. sorry. I was looking for pyspark 2.3 as my cluster is on it/

Comment: I'm worried about explode. This can make my dataframe billions of rows

Comment: You can try first. If that doesn't work I'd suggest upgrading spark. Higher order functions should offer better performance and memory usage

Comment: I have tested explode based solution and it takes couple of hours to run in my cluster. Upgrading spark is not easy as it as shared legacy system.

Comment: Then you'll have to wait for other smarter people's answer :)

Comment: @SreeramTP also included a RDD solution, though I'm not sure if that would perform well

Comment: It should be better than UDF and explode I believe

Comment: I was wondering whether some SQL based solution exists that could help me with this

Comment: @SreeramTP SQL is very similar to the dataframe API. The two dataframe operations written above can be translated to Spark SQL, but there wouldn't be any improvements for memory/speed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way without using `explode`. Get the max size of the `scores` array column. Then using a list comprehension, sum the elements (extracted float values) of the array by using python `sum` function :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

max_size = df.select(F.max(F.size("scores"))).first()[0]

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "Total",
    sum([
        F.coalesce(F.split(F.col("scores")[i], "_")[1], F.lit(0))
        for i in range(max_size)
    ])
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+----+------------------------+-----+
#|name|scores                  |Total|
#+----+------------------------+-----+
#|Dan |[1_10, 2_5, 3_2, 4_12.5]|29.5 |
#|Ann |[2_12.4, 3_4.5, 5_9.3]  |26.2 |
#|Jon |[2_1.7]                 |1.7  |
#+----+------------------------+-----+
```

For Spark 2.4+, better to use `transform` and `aggregate` functions as pointed in @mck's answer.